# How to get currency by country?

Tags: perl, currency

How would you guys figure out currency only having country code? Ideally in Perl but I think any other language solution would be easy enough to port.

Thanks

Comment: I added the "perl" tag to increase the potential audience. Always see that you add a (relevant) language or platform tag so your question is seen by people who are subscribed to that tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [Locale::Object::Currency](http://search.cpan.org/~jrobinson/Locale-Object-0.78/lib/Locale/Object/Currency.pm) from CPAN contains what you need.  It doesn't seem to have been updated since 2007, though.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Locale::Object::Currency;
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $bucks = Locale::Object::Currency->new( country_code => 'us' );
print Dumper( $bucks->symbol, $bucks->code, $bucks->name );  # etc..

#print Dumper $bucks;  # don't do this in production; use the method interface;
                       # but it does appear to have the info you need.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try finding a webservice which does this for you. For example, [webservicex.net](http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx) provides a [GetCurrencyByCountry](http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?op=GetCurrencyByCountry) operation.

The other approach is to save the country/currency mappings from somewhere into a file and then load them into a map in your program.

Comment: Unfortunately `webservicex` has very out of date info for this purpose. It has very old superseded codes for the currencies of at least Mexico, Romania, and Turkey!